# unobtrusive Ajax support in custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a fairly simple `Custom Control` derived from `HierarchicalDataBoundControl` and used to render a menu(well, a list of links) using `HierarchicalObjectDataSource`. I used an example available [@CSTrüter](http://www.cstruter.com/blog/264) if any one would be interested, and extended it a little bit.

Now I'm trying to extend it further to support unobtrusive `AJAX` by creating not regular `anchors` but mimic the output of `Ajax.ActionLink`, unfortunately with no success until now, I think that maybe I'm wrong in my approach and that's why. Currently this control can be used in form of tag `<cc:Menu runat="server"...` in bundle with another tag that defines the source for the menu and its `ID` is defined in the menu tag in `DataSourceID` attribute. I thought that I can pass the `Ajax` object to the rendering function and to use the original `Ajax.ActionLink` method, but... In order for the control to be available for use in form of `<%: cc.Menu.Render(Ajax,...) %>` the `Render` method should be static and thus the menu cannot be bounded to a source. Now, I can instantiate a new cc.Menu from within this static method, but it won't bound either since it doesn't participate in page layout, but if I would add it to the collection of controls(assuming I'll pass also the `Page` object), the page won't render since the collection is changed in the middle of iteration.

I would be happy if anyone would point me to other directions. Maybe somehow I can pass an `AjaxOptions` object as one of the attributes of the menu tag? If yes how can I then get the Ajax object from within the control? Or may be there is another way to mimic the output of `Ajax.ActionLink`?